# Populating recycle view from Task.Run()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, litedb

I'm using Xamarin Android, and in my app I have a recycle view that gets populated from LiteDB.

Now, in `OnCreateView`, in my fragment that hold the recycle view, I set the adapters, and call `SetData()`, to populate my list.

It looks like this:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Context);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new PlaylistItemAdapter(new List<YoutubePlaylistSync>());
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

SetData();
```

This works fine, but when I view the fragment the app freezes. That's normal since the call to fetch the data from the database is blocking.

I wanted to offload the work from the UI thread, so since I need to fire of and forget this function, I replaced my code with:

```
Task.Run(() => SetData());
```

This didn't work as I expected, I did confirm that the function is called and the function sets the new data, and calls `NotifyNewData()`.

```
private void SetData()
{
    mAdapter.SetData(db.GetData());
}

//In PlaylistItemAdapter
public void SetData(IEnumerable<YoutubePlaylistSync> newData)
{
    playlists.Clear();
    foreach (var playlist in newData)
    {
        playlists.Add(playlist);
    }
    NotifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

But the list is not getting populated, if I go to another tab and return, the FAB in my layout disappears, and the drawer is stuck with two items selected (navigation still works).

[image: Example]

In addition, if I don't use a task, but a new thread, I get the desired behavior. Like so:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(() =>
 {
     SetData();
 });
 t.IsBackground = true;
 t.Start();
```

Note that the app behaves normal, with the first method it works fine.
Why? Is there an alternative way to offload the DB call other than opening another thread? (Its quite an expensive operation)

Comment: All operation in LiteDB use sync methods. But,there are an option to run "Sync over Async". It´s "async=true" in connection string.

Comment: @mbdavid Hey, i tried that but had the same results, i tried it both with the `SetData()` in task, and not.

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain why the down vote ? I will greatly want to improve.